# How to solve this problem about ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero?

Tags: python, feature-extraction

```py
compactness_list = []
circularity_list = []

for contour in contours:
    perimeter =  cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)

    compactness = (perimeter ** 2) /(area)
    compactness_list.append(compactness)

    circularity = (4 * np.pi * area) / (perimeter)
    circularity_list.append(circularity)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-aa66a2f29568> in <cell line: 4>()
      6     area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
      7 
----> 8     compactness = (perimeter ** 2) / (area)
      9     compactness_list.append(compactness)
     10 

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Don't divide by 0. :-)

Comment: In the event that you would divide by 0, what do you want to happen?

Comment: `if not area:` / `print("Area of this contour is zero.")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `try...except` block:

```
for contour in contours:
    perimeter =  cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)

    try:
        compactness = (perimeter ** 2) / area
        circularity = (4 * np.pi * area) / perimeter
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        compactness = 0  # or any other value 
        circularity = 0  # or any other value 

    compactness_list.append(compactness)
    circularity_list.append(circularity)
```

Or a simple `if...else`:

```
for contour in contours:
    perimeter =  cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)

    if area == 0:  # check if area is zero
        compactness = 0  # or any other value
        circularity = 0  # or any other value
    else:
        compactness = (perimeter ** 2) / area
        circularity = (4 * np.pi * area) / perimeter

    compactness_list.append(compactness)
    circularity_list.append(circularity)
```

Comment: Ok you can go ahead and mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

in Such case you Can add epsilon to the denominator

```
import sys
compactness_list = []
circularity_list = []

epsilon = sys.float_info.epsilon
for contour in contours:
    perimeter =  cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)

    compactness = (perimeter ** 2) /(area+epsilon)
    compactness_list.append(compactness)

    circularity = (4 * np.pi * area) / (perimeter+epsilon)
    circularity_list.append(circularity)
```

Comment: @JonSG  he can do `if area != 0:` then `compactness = (perimeter ** 2) / area` if he will ignore  the contours with 0 area without returning any values.   The epsilon value ensures that even if the area or perimeter is extremely small, the division will still produce a result without causing an error.
Thanks for pointing that out about perimeter :) , i have edited my answer

Comment: Your update to include `perimeter+epsilon` resolves my concern :-)